# how to access the external website iframe having a title

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a button which when clicked opens a popup of external site and that external site has iframe in it, i want to get the title of the iframe so i can extract some data from it.

the only way i can see is to get the title of the document, because the name and id of the iframe is quite dynamic. how can i do it

any idea

I am trying something like this

but i am stuck at first step

```
<script>
var iframe = $(
iframe.onload = function() {
    // we can get the reference to the inner window
    let iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow; // OK
    try {
      // ...but not to the document inside it
      let doc = iframe.contentDocument; // ERROR
    } catch(e) {
      alert(e); // Security Error (another origin)
    }

    // also we can't READ the URL of the page in iframe
    try {
      // Can't read URL from the Location object
      let href = iframe.contentWindow.location.href; // ERROR
    } catch(e) {
      alert(e); // Security Error
    }

    // ...we can WRITE into location (and thus load something else into the iframe)!
    iframe.contentWindow.location = '/'; // OK

    iframe.onload = null; // clear the handler, not to run it after the location change
  };
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot access a foreign website HTML at all on a browser client

Comment: ok, i think i have to step by step, on my side a button is clicked, before i reach iframe, i have div in that popup, can i get that div id value